# Apache Virtual Hosts Strange Behavior

Tags: apache, virtual, hosts

I have a virtual - host file containing the following:

```
# lc.glsamcrm.com
#

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@lc.glsamcrm.com
    ServerName lc.glsamcrm.com
    ServerAlias glsamcrm.com
    DirectoryIndex index.html
    DocumentRoot /var/www/glsamcrm/htdocs/  
    ErrorLog /var/www/glsamcrm/logs/error.log
    CustomLog /var/www/glsamcrm/logs/access.log combined

    ServerAdmin webmaster@crm.glstest.com
    ServerName crm.glstest.com
    ServerAlias crm.glstest.com
    DirectoryIndex index.html
    DocumentRoot /var/www/glsamcrm_prod/htdocs/ 
    ErrorLog /var/www/glsamcrm_prod/logs/error.log
    CustomLog /var/www/glsamcrm_prod/logs/access.log combined   
</VirtualHost>
```

when I point my browser to lc.glsamcrm.com all works fine. When I point my browser to crm.glstest.com, I get the "THIS WORKS" index page located in the etc/www/ folder.  What is going on?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need two separate VirtualHost directives. This is because you can only put one ServerName, DocumentRoot, and a few others per VirtualHost.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@lc.glsamcrm.com
    ServerName lc.glsamcrm.com
    ServerAlias glsamcrm.com
    DirectoryIndex index.html
    DocumentRoot /var/www/glsamcrm/htdocs/  
    ErrorLog /var/www/glsamcrm/logs/error.log
    CustomLog /var/www/glsamcrm/logs/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@crm.glstest.com
    ServerName crm.glstest.com
    ServerAlias crm.glstest.com
    DirectoryIndex index.html
    DocumentRoot /var/www/glsamcrm_prod/htdocs/ 
    ErrorLog /var/www/glsamcrm_prod/logs/error.log
    CustomLog /var/www/glsamcrm_prod/logs/access.log combined   
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: My first configuration file looked exactly like what you posted.  Tried it once again to make sure I have everything correct but it still pulls the index page from /var/www.

Comment: Are you sure you don't have another virtual host for crm.glstest.com elsewhere? Also, try running `apache2ctl configtest` and see if there are any errors/warnings. I would also edit the "THIS WORKS" page slightly to make sure that you are actually hitting the /var/www page and not a copy of it in some other directory.

Comment: Absoutlely positive.  Ran the configtest - Syntax OK

Comment: And I assume you've restarted apache after changing the config?

Comment: Very odd.  I changed the index page in /var/www but no change.  I don't have that page anywhere else on the box.

Comment: I did...everytime I make a change.

Comment: You should check that your DNS is pointing to the box then. If it is pointing at the box, then most likely you do have that page somewhere else and you just don't know it. Also make sure you're loading a non-cached paged, ctrl-f5 for instance in firefox.

Comment: Well, I'm not sure what more to suggest. Perhaps look at your access logs and see where the requests are going. It sounds like it's probably something other than this part of the configuration.

Comment: And do you have a NameVirtualHost directive somewhere in your config file?